# ReSharper bug? Incorrect "expression is always true"

Tags: c#, resharper, expression-evaluation

I believe I have found a bug in ReSharper. Suppose I have code as follows:

```
int[] someArray = new int[10];
while (someArray  != null)
{
     //perhaps some other usage of someArray here, but not assigning it.
     SomeMethod(ref someArray );
}
```

If the local variable someArray is not assigned to null in its scope, then the statement `someArray != null` would always be true. But that isn't the case when that variable is given as ref-parameter to another method, since it could get assigned to null in that method. Then ReSharper incorrectly assumes that `someArray != null` is still always true.

I thought I'd share this information, because I'm unsure what I should do with this. Firstly I'd like someone to verify this bug, and afterwards send it to JetBrains?

Comment: And I do realise that this pattern of a while loop waiting for another method to set a variable to null is far, far from esthetic, but that's not the point.

Comment: it looks like other code inside loop could trigger that. do you have breaks, return or continue control statements inside?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't have the exact code with me at the moment, I will post that in a few hours. I should mention, also to Kirk Woll, that I haven't tested precisely the code I pasted in the question, so indeed it might be caused by the surrounding code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hm, apparently the static analysis of ReSharper is smarter than me....
The code in which I correctly get the "expression is always true" warning is:

```
int[] someArray = new int[10];
while (someArray != null)
{
    Foo(ref someArray);
    someArray.Bar();
}
```

I get the warning that `someArray != null` is redundant, so I thought ReSharper misinterpreted the ref parameter, since `someArray` can in fact be assigned to null. But that is not the reason why the warning is correct. Then a subtle fact plays a role: that `someArray` is null would mean that the method invocation of `Bar` would throw a `NullReferenceException`, and with that alter the control flow such that the start of the while loop isn't reached. So even when `someArray` is assigned to null in Foo, the warning is correct.

My mistake, and thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this loop to do-while and check what ReSharper marks it in this situation. Is it still always true?
But on first loop, it is really "always true", so ReSharper evaluates it correctly (it is static analysis).

Comment: The fact that the expression is always true the first time it is executed is not important, since static analysis should be able to figure out it will be executed multiple times. Most importantly, Resharper suggests I substitute 'someArray != null' for 'true', which is obviously wrong. So its evaluation is not correct.